# Midlet is not abstract and does not override abstract method focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Component)

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-list, lwuit-label

I have a LWUIT class which has a `List`, the list itself contains a Label as an item.

My idea simply to make an action for the list when I focus on the label.

I get the following error, when compiling the class:

> anonymous Midlet$2 is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Component) in
>   com.sun.lwuit.events.FocusListener

```
String s = ("Focus me");
final com.sun.lwuit.Form f  = new com.sun.lwuit.Form();
final com.sun.lwuit.List D  = new com.sun.lwuit.List();
final com.sun.lwuit.Label l = new com.sun.lwuit.Label(s);

D.addItem(l);
f.addComponent(D);

D.addFocusListener(new com.sun.lwuit.events.FocusListener () {

    public void focusGained(com.sun.lwuit.Label l)
    {
    }
    public void focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Label l)
    {
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All details of what is wrong with your code are in the error message, you just need to carefully read it. Look,

1. word `anonymous` and sign `$` in `Midlet$2` tell you something is wrong in the anonymous class.
   In your code snippet, there's only one such class: `new com.sun.lwuit.events.FocusListener`
2. `does not override abstract method focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Component)` means your anonymous class misses a definition of a method with such a signature (signature is method name and type of parameters)
3. Look closer in the methods you defined in that anonymous class, is there a method compiler is complaining about?
4. At the first glance, you may think it's there, there's a method called `focusLost` - but (!) you need to remember that signature is not only method name, but also parameters type - and (!) if you look closer, you'll find out that parameter type is not that is said to be required in error message.

Your anonymous class has method `focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Label)` but error message says there should be method with different signature (different parameter type) - `focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Component)`.

To fix this compilation error, add to the anonymous class `new com.sun.lwuit.events.FocusListener` a method with required signature: `focusLost(com.sun.lwuit.Component)`.